# Javascript - Vue js fetch from file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, get, fetch-api

I am just learning Vue js and are using it in the simplest possible way by including the source code in the end of the html. Now I am trying to do an ordinary JavaScript fetch like this:

```
fetch('./json_docs/example.json')
   .then(function(response) {
      return response;
   })
   .then(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
  });
```

The response I get looks like this but I don't get the actual data back. When I try using the URL to the file that's included in the response in the browser the data shows. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

> Response { type: "basic", url: "file:///Users/danielamir/Documents/…", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, bodyUsed: false }

Comment: Call `.json` on the `response`.  See [Making Fetch Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Making_fetch_requests)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, it just returns 'function json()' when I log response.json @zero298

Comment: **Call** it with `.json()` using parentheses.  See my answer.

Comment: Also, seeing `file://` in the URL of the response worries me.  How are you serving this content?  Does the URL in your address bar have `file://` in it?

Comment: I am getting a file just as a test, so that's why @zero298

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually call `.json` on the `response`:

```
fetch('./json_docs/example.json')
   .then(function(response) {
      return response.json(); // As a function call
   })
   .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  });
```

See [Making Fetch Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Making_fetch_requests)